# Get only these JSON values with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a JSON like this :

```json
[
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Albums",
    "slug": "albums",
    "parent": 11,
    "description": "",
    "display": "default",
    "image": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "count": 4,
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/15"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
        }
      ],
      "up": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/11"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And I would like to get id, name and parent values only and transform them in a CSV file.
How can I get that ?

Here is my current code :

```py
from woocommerce import API

import pandas as pd
...
products = wcapi.get("products/categories", params={"per_page": 100})
total_pages = int(products.headers['X-WP-TotalPages'])

for i in range(1,total_pages+1):
    r = wcapi.get("products/categories?&page="+str(i), params={"per_page": 100}).json()
    df = pd.json_normalize(r)
    df.to_csv('categories.csv', mode='a', index=False, encoding='utf-8') # Save all in a file
```

Example of CSV file I would like to get :

```
15;Albums;11
9;Clothing;0
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(js, orient='columns')` ????? then you can select desired columns. you can either `create list of dict` if data is not too large and then convert them to dataframe once. But if the data is too large use `csv` module open and close the file after storing `n` number of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas can read JSON and output to CSV with a custom separator.

```
import pandas as pd

j = [
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Albums",
    "slug": "albums",
    "parent": 11,
    "description": "",
    "display": "default",
    "image": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "count": 4,
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/15"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories"
        }
      ],
      "up": [
        {
          "href": "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories/11"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(j, columns=['id','name','parent'])
df.to_csv('/tmp/out.csv', sep=';')
```

Depending on how your "Clothing" and other end rows appear in the initial JSON, we may have to re-orient the columns, but I can't tell you exactly how to do that unless your input has more data in it.

Comment: I was definitely looking in the wrong documentation... Thanks